# embedding .jar in html (to RC a Raspberry Pi)

Tags: java, html, raspberry-pi

I'm working in a project; we want to remote control a toy-car via 2 Raspberry Pi's (1 in the Car, 1 in the remote). It's all running so far, the remote can be used (touch display) to drive around with the car.

We used Java so there is a .jar running on the remote Raspberry.

We also want to implement a feature allowing remote control from the web.

I know, after reading a bit, how to add a .jar in a website. But it will take a few days, till our web server is online and I could test it..

So I wanted to ask, will it be possible for the Java App, if running in a browser, to remotely control the car? I mean, the App is sending information (e.g. "Button left pressed") to a "Server" (which is our Router, both Raspberrys are connected to)

Or do I have to change things?

Comment: If the text is hard to understand... Sorry for it.
What I wanted to ask is, if I place a working .jar in a Website(the .jar is communicating with a locale Server) would the .jar work normal or do I have to change (many) to get it working

Comment: @Jason Aller,
thanks for correcting my text :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to make a request to the server, like a REST Request. So that, every time you are calling the `http://localhost/moveLeftButton` where `http://localhost` is handled by your web server, an action is triggered.

It depends how you have implemented your server. Try to have a look here: [IBM Java and REST](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-rest/index.html?ca=dat).

If you need some more complex communication (=stream), I can advice you javascript, streaming via web via websocket, using node.js and socket.io, you can find [here](http://ni-c.github.io/heimcontrol.js/) some example with the rasp.

EDIT: using a .jar for a server and a .jar for an applet inside the browser sand box are two really different stories. I think it would be not so easy to let it work, and the java applet technology is pretty old. I advice you to do not try this, and just try to send messages from the browser to a server that is running on the raspberry.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the fast Answer.
I never worked with Java before this Project (started a week ago)
And so I thought, it might be the easiest way to setup the Web control by simply adding the Java Program into a Website. Especially, because our program is not really complex (Button1 pressed, Server recieves a notification and informs the 2nd Raspberry which changes his GPIO )

Comment: send HTTP request is the simplest thing!

Comment: See your *.jar as the interface to your car. Now you need an interface to your jar. As @nkint wrote, this can be an HTTP server with a REST-like interface. The only thing you'll want is to start your JVM only once and not for every request. That HTTP server could be a Servlet container (eg. Tomcat, though heavy - you may have to run it on lower resources) or node.js with the java bridge (https://www.npmjs.org/package/java). You could also run lighttpd with php and its own java bridge.

Comment: Thanks okiharaherbst, for this complexe Answer.

Comment: Another funny thought that my colleague just brought up: with an HTTP interface, you could have more than one client making (almost) simultaneous requests. If designing a web remote control is part of your project, you may want to think carefully about making it robust and safe. There are a few mechanisms that you can use (eg. cookies) to  grant control to only one web client. At the same time, you could easily use the same server in read mode to provide live statistics to any number of clients.

Comment: yess! anyway you don't strictly need a jar applet in the page for doing that

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel for this. Just bundle your .jar within a .war file and deploy it to java ee server that you would use to provide the HTTP/HTML interface. For example, [JBoss can be run just fine on Raspberry PI](http://blog.oliver-mueller.com/-135), and I've done it myself as well.

The interface could be for example REST interface mentioned, or any other HTTP based interface. HTML-based interface might be the easiest to work with, depending on your use case.